# Buckets in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, bucket

Can any tell me how to make buckets of equal sizes in PostgreSQL. For Example I have Ids:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15.

Now I want to make 3 buckets of equal sizes so there will be 3 buckets containing 5 records each , like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `ntile()`:

```
select t.*,
       ntile(3) over (order by id) as bucket
from t;
```

Note:  These will be as equal in size as possible, if the number of tiles does not divide the number of records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I tried this but this does not provide bucket of equal sizes if number of tiles does not divide the number of records. I want bucket of equal sizes no matter if number of tiles divide number of records or not.

Comment: @VijayKumarKhatri . . . You have t explain that in the question when the number of buckets does not evenly divide into the number of rows.

Comment: I found the solution to it .
'select FLOOR((a.id-1)/5)+1 as bucket,a.cid,name from customer a
order by bucket,cid' This will make bucket of ids of size 5 for each bucket

Comment: @VijayKumarKhatri . . . That doesn't work if the ids have gaps.

Comment: Yeah but this works fine for the question asked above. This solution is custom made for sequential ids.

Comment: @VijayKumarKhatri . . . This solution always creates 3 groups that are as equal in size as possible.

Comment: Lets suppose you have 1-26 ids then it will generate total of 6 buckets with 5 buckets of size 5 and 1 of size 1,since 5 buckets will occupy 25 ids and remaining 1 will go to 6th bucket. I have run this query at my own and it runs fine for sequential ids